# How to play videos in sd card

Tags: android

Am trying to play videos which i have in my sd card but it is showing an error that video cannot be played.. My code is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);

        mPath.setText("mnt/sdcard/music/jelly jamm.3gp");
```

Can anyone help me.. I tried all the posts in stack overflow but still getting same error

Comment: Should we just guess away what error you get, or will you post it? Ain't no brain-readers here, apart from Jon Skeet of course.

Comment: please post the logcat logs.. you should not hard code the path, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory`  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the path to the sd card..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/music/jelly jamm.3gp");
             intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "video/mp4");
             startActivity(intent);
```

try like this. Hope this will give you some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to play video from sdcard

```
    VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    File root;
    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Log.d("FILEPATH1", root.toString());

    String path =root.toString()+"/music/jelly jamm.3gp";

    MediaController mc= new MediaController(getApplicationContext());

    vv.setVideoPath(path);

    vv.setMediaController(mc);

    vv.requestFocus();

    vv.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you post the error you are getting we can help you...

May be your video is incompatible with Android. Try it with a different video. like any .mp4 video definitely works with Android. If that video works, and yours does not, then your video is not compatible with Android.
and do test this on a device. Video playback on the emulator requires too much power.